# Keep hover effect on child while hovering parent if child isnt inside parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple example on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/to1hmg1L/

As you can see, when you hover over `.parent` the `.child` will show up. The problem is that when you hover over `.child` it disappears. Because the `.parent` isnt the real parent (child isnt inside the parent's div).
I want to keep `.child` visible when hovering over `.parent` and `.child`.
I just want to create something like popup window (menu dropdown). Please solutions only with HTML, CSS and JS only.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #32CD32;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  
}
.child {
  background: #bada55;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: none;

}
.parent:hover + .child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div><div class="child"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this, you can specify that you also want the `.child` to have `display:block` when it is hovered by adding `, .child:hover` to your CSS :

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #32CD32;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  
}
.child {
  background: #bada55;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  display: none;

}
.parent:hover + .child, .child:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div><div class="child"></div>
```